# How do I delete the blank space of the webpage, on the right side? , maintaining it responsive, obviusly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I expect that there was not blank space in the right side. I don't know how, in this case modify the Bootstrap code, nor how to code the CSS to obtain the desired layout or if I need to put margin 0 or padding 0 somewhere in the code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-text {
  color: #707070;
}

.card-img-top {
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#form_title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#form_button {
  text-align: center;
}

b {
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta viewport="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CUPPON</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/CSS/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CUPPON</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/plumón.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Plumón de cama">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Plumón Coral Fleece estampado en modelo y tamaño a elección</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Plumones Manolino<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    9191 Avenida Vitacura, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$45.990</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$20.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/plato.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Plato de comida gourmet">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Entrada para compartir + platos de fondo + postres + bebestibles</h5>
                <p class="card-text">V for Vegan<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    777 Jesse Pinkman, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$60.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$10.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/dentista.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Sala dental">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Tratamiento Dental Integral</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Clínica Dental CumCum<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    258 Papelucho Street, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$350.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$180.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/charquican.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Charquicán">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Plato Típico Chileno</h5>
                <p class="card-text">La Maestranza<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    Local 20, Barrio Franklin, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$8.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$5.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/kids.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="Centro recreacional para niños">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">2 Entradas para Kidzito</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Kidzito<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    654 Chatacura, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$18.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$10.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/san_pedro.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="San Pedro de Atacama">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Derecho de Alojamiento en Carpa en San Pedro de Atacama</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Atacama Camping<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    San Pedro de Atacama, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">45.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$20.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <form>
        <h5 id="form_title">Recibe cupones en tu correo</h5>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" aria-describedby="nameHelp">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
        </div>
        <div id="form_button">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</footer>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e186ec11fa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put margin 0 and padding 0 in the body, nothing changes. I'd appreciate any help to correct my code.

Comment: Putting your `<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">` section inside of a `<div class="container-fluid">` should eliminate the space you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

**You need use container or container-fluid on outside of row because row are use minus margin, so there is generating scrollbar.**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-text {
  color: #707070;
}

.card-img-top {
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#form_title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#form_button {
  text-align: center;
}

b {
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta viewport="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CUPPON</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/CSS/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CUPPON</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid py-3">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/plumón.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Plumón de cama">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Plumón Coral Fleece estampado en modelo y tamaño a elección</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Plumones Manolino<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    9191 Avenida Vitacura, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$45.990</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$20.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/plato.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Plato de comida gourmet">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Entrada para compartir + platos de fondo + postres + bebestibles</h5>
                <p class="card-text">V for Vegan<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    777 Jesse Pinkman, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$60.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$10.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/dentista.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Sala dental">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Tratamiento Dental Integral</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Clínica Dental CumCum<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    258 Papelucho Street, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$350.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$180.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/charquican.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Charquicán">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Plato Típico Chileno</h5>
                <p class="card-text">La Maestranza<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    Local 20, Barrio Franklin, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$8.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$5.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/kids.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="Centro recreacional para niños">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">2 Entradas para Kidzito</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Kidzito<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    654 Chatacura, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">$18.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$10.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="assets/img/san_pedro.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="San Pedro de Atacama">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Derecho de Alojamiento en Carpa en San Pedro de Atacama</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Atacama Camping<br><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                    San Pedro de Atacama, Chile</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">45.000</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <b>$20.000</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
    <form>
        <h5 id="form_title">Recibe cupones en tu correo</h5>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" aria-describedby="nameHelp">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
        </div>
        <div id="form_button">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</footer>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e186ec11fa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```